# Sonatype buildNumber and timestamp out of sync

Tags: maven, deployment, sbt, sonatype

I have a really weird problem with my snapshot deployment: https://gist.github.com/fommil/5042065

```
<groupId>com.github.fommil</groupId>
<artifactId>emokit</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<versioning>
    <snapshot>
        <timestamp>20130226.204310</timestamp>
        <buildNumber>13</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20130226204310</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20130226.204248-12</value>
            <updated>20130226204310</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
    ...
```

Basically, the `buildNumber` and `timestamp` do not agree with the names of the `snapshotVersion`s, which confuses SBT and IntelliJ to the point where I can't depend on these snapshots.

I have tried deleting and redeploying all the snapshots, but it hasn't fixed it.

I'd like somebody to help me fix this so that the fields all agree and I can use SBT as my build tool in upstream applications. I filed an issue on SBT but it has received no attention (this is arguably an SBT bug in not dealing with this): https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/679

The project itself is hosted at https://github.com/fommil/emokit-java and the uploaded file (which will change) is sourced at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/fommil/emokit/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Sometimes it fixes itself - I expect there was some sonatype cronjob that tidied this all up.

(NOTE: I voted to close because I thought it seemed to fix itself, but then the problem arose again.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared the maven-deploy-plugin specifically in your pom?  Double check the version and  of that plugin.

Comment: removing the `maven-deploy-plugin` from my `pom.xml` did the trick! perhaps it was overriding the settings from a super pom. Thanks!

Comment: damn, just realised I've lost attached sources by removing those lines.

Comment: Hmm, I think I just fixed it by turning on the `sonatype-oss-release` profile - which has deployed to the snapshot repo.