# How to use commit SHA as buildNumber in sonatype snapshots

Tags: git, maven, deployment, sonatype

How can I set up my snapshot releases so that the `buildNumber` is replaced with the Git commit SHA? This has to work for Sonatype OSS snapshots.

And, if possible, how can I force the deployment to fail if there are uncommitted changes in my repository?

I started thinking about this when wrestling with [Sonatype buildNumber and timestamp out of sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055688)

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) to pick up the SHA-1 from the Git that is configured by the  tag. Configure the [doCheck](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#doCheck) parameter to fail a build if any file has been updated (default is *false*).

For details, read the [blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/07/continuous-deployment-versioning-and-git/) that I wrote some time ago.

Comment: thanks. I had already found your blog post, but I don't believe it is doing what I'm asking – I'm looking to put the `buildNumber` in the Maven `metadata.xml` and the filename of the deployed `jar`s, not some internally referenced manifest. Note that the `${buildNumber}` variable in `pom.xml` doesn't seem to imply anything on the `timestamp`/`buildNumber` in the eventual Sonatype deployment.

Comment: also, `doCheck` is a bit harsh – I'd only want that for `deploy`, not `compile`.